# Compress two or more numbers into one byte

Tags: algorithm, math

I think this is not really possible but worth asking anyway. Say I have two small numbers (Each ranges from 0 to 11). Is there **a way** that I can compress them into one byte and get them back later. How about with four numbers of similar sizes.

What I need is something like: a1 + a2 = x. I only know x and from that get a1, a2
For the second part: a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 = x. I only know x and from that get a1, a2, a3, a4
*Note: I know you cannot unadd, just illustrating my question.*

x must be one byte. a1, a2, a3, a4 range [0, 11].

Comment: 11 is 1011 in binary, so it requires only 4 bits. So yes, it should be possible. You've have to left shift it four times, then add them. After that, to retrieve them get the first four bits and the last four bits.

Comment: This smells a little bit like homework to me.

Comment: Nope I assure you this is my own research, School doesn't start till September ;-)

Comment: @Esteban, no, sounds more like data compression. I came to this problem also in data compression, and solved it, see my post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thats trivial with bit masks. Idea is to divide byte into smaller units and dedicate them to different elements.

For 2 numbers, it can be like this: first 4 bits are number1, rest are number2. You would use `number1 = (x & 0b11110000) >> 4`, `number2 = (x & 0b00001111)` to retrieve values, and `x = (number1 << 4) | number2` to compress them.

Comment: for those who are new to bit shifting: this only works for numbers that can be represented with 4 bits (2 ^ 4) = numbers 0 - 15. The reason is because what you are doing here is storing a value (in 4 bits) then shifting them over 4 places and storing the next number in that spot. Since a byte is only 8 bits, you only have room for two 4 bit numbers, thus limiting this approach to small numbers.

Answer (score 9):

For two numbers, sure. Each one has 12 possible values, so the pair has a total of 12^2 = 144 possible values, and that's less than the 256 possible values of a byte. So you could do e.g.

```
x = 12*a1 + a2
a1 = x / 12
a2 = x % 12
```

(If you only have signed bytes, e.g. in Java, it's a little trickier)

For four numbers from 0 to 11, there are 12^4 = 20736 values, so you couldn't fit them in one byte, but you could do it with two.

```
x = 12^3*a1 + 12^2*a2 + 12*a3 + a4
a1 = x / 12^3
a2 = (x / 12^2) % 12
a3 = (x / 12) % 12
a4 = x % 12
```

**EDIT:** the other answers talk about storing one number per four bits and using bit-shifting. That's faster.

Comment: The shifting is faster in this specific case but I appreciate the simple entropy computation here because it's more generic :) It's worth noting that shifting is an optimization that is only applied once you've determined that there could be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The 0-11 example is pretty easy -- you can store each number in four bits, so putting them into a single byte is just a matter of shifting one 4 bits to the left, and `or`ing the two together.

Four numbers of similar sizes won't fit -- four bits apiece times four gives a minimum of 16 bits to hold them.

Comment: nitpick - 16 bits is not the minimum bits needed to hold 4 numbers 0-11 you can use less bits at the expense of not being able to encode/decode them as quickly

Comment: @jk: well, yes, you could get by with fewer than 16, but it still takes more than 8.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say it in general: suppose you want to mix N numbers a1, a2, ... aN, a1 ranging from 0..k1-1, a2 from 0..k2-1, ... and aN from 0 .. kN-1.

Then, the encoded number is:

```
encoded = a1 + k1*a2 + k1*k2*a3 + ... k1*k2*..*k(N-1)*aN
```

The decoding is then more tricky, stepwise:

```
rest = encoded
a1 = rest mod k1
rest = rest div k1

a2 = rest mod k2
rest = rest div k2

...

a(N-1) = rest mod k(N-1)
rest = rest div k(N-1)

aN = rest # rest is already < kN
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers 0-11 aren't evenly distributed you can do even better by using shorter bit sequences for common values and longer ones for rarer values. It costs at least one bit to code which length you are using so there is a whole branch of CS devoted to proving when it's worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

So a byte can hold upto 256 values or FF in Hex.  So you can encode two numbers from 0-16 in a byte.

```
byte a1 = 0xf;
byte a2 = 0x9;
byte compress = a1 << 4 | (0x0F & a2);  // should yield 0xf9 in one byte.
```

4 Numbers you can do if you reduce it to only 0-8 range.

Comment: "4 Numbers you can do if you reduce it to only 0-8 range."  Ummmmm.... maybe 0-3 range? 2 bits per number...4 numbers, 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Since a single byte is 8 bits, you can easily subdivide it, with smaller ranges of values. The extreme limit of this is when you have 8 single bit integers, which is called a bit field.

If you want to store two 4-bit integers (which gives you 0-15 for each), you simply have to do this:

```
value = a * 16 + b;
```

As long as you do proper bounds checking, you will never lose any information here.

To get the two values back, you just have to do this:

```
a = floor(value / 16)
b = value MOD 15
```

MOD is modulus, it's the "remainder" of a division.

If you want to store four 2-bit integers (0-3), you can do this:

```
value = a * 64 + b * 16 + c * 4 + d
```

And, to get them back:

```
a = floor(value / 64)
b = floor(value / 16) MOD 4
c = floor(value / 4) MOD 4
d = value MOD 4
```

I leave the last division as an exercise for the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Caron

your last example (4 integers between 0-3) is much faster with bit-shifting. No need for floor().

```
value = (a << 6) | (b << 4) | (c << 2) | d;

a = (value >> 6);
b = (value >> 4) % 4;
c = (value >> 2) % 4;
d = (value) % 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bit masking or Bit Shifting. The later is faster

Test out BinaryTrees for some fun. (it will be handing later on in dev life regarding data and all sorts of dev voodom lol)

Answer (score 0):

Packing four values into one number will require at least 15 bits. This doesn't fit in a single byte, but in two.

What you need to do is a conversion from base 12 to base 65536 and conversely.

```
B = A1 + 12.(A2 + 12.(A3 + 12.A4))

A1 = B % 12
A2 = (B / 12) % 12
A3 = (B / 144) % 12
A4 = B / 1728
```

---

As this takes 2 bytes anyway, conversion from base 12 to (packed) base 16 is by far prefable.

```
B1 = A1 + 256.A2
B2 = A3 + 256.A4

A1 = B1 % 256
A2 = B1 / 256
A3 = B2 % 256
A4 = B2 / 256
```

The modulos and divisions are implemented bymaskings and shifts.

Answer (score 0):

0-9 works much easier. You can easily store 11random order decimals in 4 1/2 bytes. Which is tighter compression than log(256)÷log(10). Just by creative mapping. Remember not all compression has to do with, dictionaries, redundancies, or sequences.

If you are talking of random numbers 0 - 9 you can have 4  digits per 14 bits not 15.