# Bit compression ( two 8 bits in 13 bits register)

Tags: compression, bit

I have two 8 bits data (For ex: A and B). But i have only 13 bits register. How can i save two 8 bits data ( A and B ) in 13 bits register by applying some algorithm ( C = A func B) so that i can reconstruct A and B from that saved C data..?

Comment: Probably worth taking a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499444/compress-two-or-more-numbers-into-one-byte

Comment: No, it is impossible to store 16 bits of arbitrary data in a 13-bit register. Compression does not help. You should reduce the amount of information that needs to be stored, or increase the amount of storage.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "compress" 16 bits in a 13 bits register and "decompress" them back to the original 16 bits. When you have 2^13 = 8192 possible values for your register `C` then you can have only 2^13 = 8192 possible combinations for the original registers `A` and `B`. You have only mappings for 8192 combinations, but are missing the remaining 57344 combinations (65536 - 8192 = 57344). This is somehow related to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).